# iMessage iCloud - Time Machine Restore

Tags: macos, icloud, messages-in-icloud

I was trying to free up space on my iPad and accidentally hit delete iMessage history after 1 year in iMessage- thinking it would just affect the iPad. Since I had iMessage in iCloud enabled it deleted all my iMessage history after 1 year from all of my devices (iPhone, Mac, iPad) as well as in iCloud (~10 years of iMessage history (25GB)). I didn't have it in an iCloud backup since I was using iMessage in iCloud.  I thought I had permanently lost it but remembered I have been doing Time Machine backups on my Mac which is synced with iCloud iMessages.

My question is: I restored the iMessage database (including all conversations, attachments, etc) from that iMessage Time Machine backup on my Mac and all of the messages are showing properly on my Mac. I thought once I enabled iCloud iMessage on my Mac it would push the old (previously deleted now restored) messages onto iCloud and down to my iPhone and iPad. It is not giving an error it just will not upload the old messages to iCloud.

Comment: What do you mean it will not resync to iCloud?  How are you trying to 'resync'?  Are you getting any errors?  If so, what are they?  How are you checking if they've synced or not?  There's a lot of info missing from your question, you can [edit] your question to add the info.

Comment: Try sending a message to one of the contacts where the conversation was restored but not sent back to the cloud.  See if that prompts a re-sync.

Comment: @Allan - Yes I tried that. It shows back up on the other devices but only with the new messages, not the old messages located on the MacOS iMessage.

Comment: Then I don't know how to force it.  When I had my iPhone replaced, the iCloud restore brought all the conversations back.  Maybe try turning on iCloud backup temporarily so so that all the messages can be backed up to iCloud then restore again to your phone.

Comment: Having the same problem in 2021. Did anyone find a solution?